# Should SQL Server min and max memory settings be fixed to the same value

Tags: sql-server, memory, database-administration

[image]

Hello,
If the server has the resources to dedicate to the SQL server should you keep the min and max server memory settings fixed at the same value?
Will setting the values the same produce any performance benefit by keeping the memory available constant? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running SQL server in a VM the minimum server memory should be the same as the startup memory for the VM. With the maximum server memory you should give some greater number than minimum taking into consideration that SQL server starts using all available configured memory and won't release it until the next restart. So the maximum server memory is the actual value the SQL server is going to be using most of the time.

Comment: Additionally, you should configure your maximum memory amount to leave (if possible) a couple GB for the OS to operate.  To get maximum performance out of the server you should only use it for SQL and only have users logging in to the server when required.  If you installed any other SQL components on the server then you will need to leave additional overhead memory available for those services or you will see a performance impact.